# Watin doesn't load pages when IE is minimized

Tags: c#, watin

I am using Watin to make requests to Google and read some tags of the response. 
What happens is that when my IE (the one loaded by watin) is minimized it does not render the responses (And my watin code fails). If my IE is maximized and focused it works great.

Maybe that´s IE behavior.

Any help?

Comment: Can you collaborate more on what watin and IE version you are using?

Comment: I am using Watin 2.1 and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

With IE minimized I'm still able to navigate the DOM without issue.  Tony, posting your code would be a help.

**Code**

```
IE browser = new IE();
browser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Minimize);
browser.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
Console.WriteLine("Search Button text: " + browser.Span("gbqfsa").Text);
```

**Output**

Search Button text: Google Search

I'm running Win7 64bit, IE9, Watin 2.1.  Test run using the GUI runner NUnit 2.5

Comment: OCary, I navigate the DOM, but my IE doesn´t open the pages. It keeps loading the site forever. If I use the browser without watin it has the same behavior. It takes to much to load the page if I am not focusing it.